# Encoding method for a categorical variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

Suppose we have a categorical variable

`Age['0-17','18-25','35-40','55+']`

What should we prefer; **OneHotEncoding**, **LabelEncoding** or **Mapping** (like assigning data values such as `'0-17':1`, `'18-25':2`) and Why?

Comment: Do you only have four range : `'0-17','18-25','35-40','55+'`??

Comment: yes, but if we would increase it upto 10 what changes would it have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with pure python like below:

```
age = ['0-17','18-25','35-40','40-55', '55-70', '70-85', '85+']
rng = range(len(age))
# If you want label start from '1' 
# rng = range(1,len(age)+1)
res = dict(zip(age, rng))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'0-17': 0, '18-25': 1, '35-40': 2, '40-55': 3, '55-70': 4, '70-85': 5, '85+': 6}
```